# Why Browser Loads first HTML Then Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I refresh my page bootstrap page. First The browser loads like below image. Then The browser loads like second image. Why The browser render the page. I do not know. please have a look at it and give me a suggestion.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: please provide details...a fiddle replicating this issue.

Comment: That's probably because the css isn't in the `head`-element, or because it's rendered with javascript, or because some resources aren't loaded.

Comment: Please provide your codes

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to Bootstrap CDN on a weak internet connection the local files will load before or without the bootstrap styles.

If this is the case you can simply download the bootstrap files and link to them locally.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your bootstrap.css is loaded before you load any JS scripts. Ideally, place your `<link rel='stylesheet'>` before your `<script>`s .